# Привязка названия раздела и подраздела в почтовом сообщении Битрикс

Tags: битрикс, шаблоны, email

Столкнулся с проблемой. Когда приходит заказ, то в сообщении указывается только наименование позиции. Нужно сделать чтобы также указывалось наименование раздела и подраздела. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где и что можно поменять? Второй день мучаюсь и вас мучаю..... Битрикс все нервы вымотал)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На последнем скрине вы можете увидеть Секция и раздел названия, увы, я сам их туда как-то вписал и даже если я их указываю в сообщении, то они не несут в себе необходимой информации.

Answer (score 0):

Добавляете обработчик события https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/events/onbeforeeventadd.php

и проверяете тип почтового события

`if($event == "ASPRO_SEND_FORM_ADMIN_109"){
// и здесь делаете зпрос к заказу, собираете id товаров и по ним достаете названия разделов
}`